# Group count and Pivot Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Group count and Pivot Query]

If Docs with A and B then count added to DocCompleted. If only A or B or Null then count added to unCompleted.

```
create table #TempRecords
(
EmpId int not null,
Doc_Name nvarchar(50),
DateCreated datetime ,

)

insert into #TempRecords values
(1001,'Doc_A','2016-10-15 07:57:37'),
(1001,'Doc_B','2016-10-15 07:57:37'),
(1001,'Doc_A','2016-10-15 07:57:37'),
(1001,'Doc_A','2016-10-15 07:57:37'),

(2001,'Doc_A','2016-10-15 07:57:37'),
(2001,'Doc_B','2016-10-15 07:57:37'),
(2001,'Doc_A','2016-10-15 07:57:37'),
(2001,'Doc_A','2016-10-15 07:57:37'),

(3001,null,null),
(3001,'Doc_A','2016-10-15 14:57:37'),
(3004,null,null)


select * from #TempRecords
```

Comment: Perhaps you have tried something that you can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*) as EmpCount,
       sum(case when num_a > 0 and num_b > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as DocCompletedCount,
       sum(case when num_a = 0 or num_b = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as DocUnCompletedCount
from (select empid,
             sum(case when doc_name = 'Doc_A' then 1 else 0 end) as num_a,
             sum(case when doc_name = 'Doc_B' then 1 else 0 end) as num_b
      from #temprecords
      group by empid
     ) t;
```

Or, if you want to be fancy (concise?):

```
select count(*) as EmpCount,
       sum(has_a * has_b),
       sum(1 - has_a * has_b) as DocUnCompletedCount
from (select empid,
             max(case when doc_name = 'Doc_A' then 1 else 0 end) as has_a,
             max(case when doc_name = 'Doc_B' then 1 else 0 end) as has_b
      from #temprecords
      group by empid
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Count(Distinct ...) and a conditional aggregation may do the trick

```
Select EmpCount = count(Distinct EmpID)
      ,DocCompletedCount = count(Distinct Doc_Name)
      ,unCompletedCount = sum(case when Doc_Name is null then 1 else 0 end)
 From  #TempRecords
```

Returns

```
EmpCount    DocCompletedCount   unCompletedCount
4           2                   2
```

Comment: @Rosebud Looking at Gordon's answer ... I may have over-simplified your question

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but what does the # in front of the table name do?  It seems like it does nothing at all.  When I removed it, all solutions worked for me.  Just curious.